# Adding a link to a HTML submit button

Tags: php, html

I'm just getting into mysql and i am creating a basic registration page. However, when i click submit, i want to be directed to another page, say a page where you login, as many sites have.

How do i go about allowing the submit button to link to a new page. I know it'll be something simple, but i have looked and can't seem to find much on it.

This is the current code that i've tried:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>MySQL Test - Registration</title>
    <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
        function testResults() {
        window.document.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action = "rego.php" method = "POST">
        Username:<br/>
        <input type = "text" name = "username"/><br/>
        Password:<br/>
        <input type = "password" name = "password"/><br/>
        Confirm Password:<br/>
        <input type = "password" name = "passvery"/><br/>
        Email:<br/>
        <input type = "text" name = "email"/><br/><br/>

        Please select your gender:<br/>
        <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "male"/>Male &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "female"/>Female<br/><br/>

        <input type = "checkbox" name = "agree" value = "agree"/>I agree to the terms and conditions.<br/>
        <br/>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Sign Up!" onclick = "javascript:testresults()" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just redirect from your `rego.php` script?

Comment: You want some processing to happen in `rego.php` (i.e. adding a record to a database or informing the user they've already registered with that e-mail address). So after you've inserted the new record, redirect the user to the login page.

Comment: You can add a header call in your PHP script to perform the redirect. Also your function needs to be camelCased in your submit handler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Form action="rego.php" means that your form will be submitted to that file.

If you want to go somewhere else  after rego.php, you should redirect from that file, for example using the location header, before any output:

```
// do stuff (registration)

header("Location: another-php.php");
```

Comment: ah i have completely forgot about this :( I Havn't written in PHP/HTML in quite a while and have basically just started again. Thankyou!

Comment: I have discovered a problem with this, and that is if I want to go back to the registration page, I'm not able to, it just redirects me to the header page. Is there a way around this?

Comment: what do you mean by "go back"? redisplaying the registration form in case of errors? For that, you may use a condition. if(registrationSuccess()){ redirect }else{ display the form again }